# Como borrar markers en leatflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Muy buenas tardes estoy desarrollando un visor para el seguimiento de vehiculos, hasta ahora ya he logrado cargar ya todos los puntos en mi mapa, el punto es que cada cierto tiempo este metodo es llamado nuevamente y vuelve a crear nuevos puntos en el mapa mi pregunta es como borrar los puntos anteriores que fueron cargados estoy usando leatflet.

```
function recuperarLastLocation() {
  var id_user = sessionStorage.getItem("id_user");
  var bearer_token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
  console.log(bearer_token);
  var details = {
    'id': id_user,
  };
  var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'img/camion.png',
    iconSize: [14, 48], // size of the icon
    shadowSize: [25, 32], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor: [11, 47], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [2, 31], // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
  });
  var marker_actual;
  var formBody = [];
  for (var property in details) {
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }
  formBody = formBody.join("&");
  var bearer = 'Bearer ' + bearer_token;
  console.log('Obteniendo los datos de la API...');
  fetch('https://apiservice.servertrack.co:3006/raptortrack/app/content/last_location', {
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': bearer,
      'content-length': "57",
    },
    body: formBody
  }).then(
    res => res.json()
  ).then(
    data => {
      console.log('Created Gist:', data)
      var gejos = convertir(data)
      let geoJsonlayer = L.geoJson(gejos, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
          pass = bearer_token
          movil = feature.properties['movil']
          layer.bindPopup("<a onclick='javascript:recuperarFollow(pass,movil)'>Click Seguir Vehiculo." + feature.properties['movil'] + "</a>")
        }
      }).addTo(map)
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás añadiendo un layer con los marcadores cada vez que los recuperas? Podrías usar siempre el mismo layer y limpiarlo antes de insertar los nuevos o guardarte la referencia al último layer cargado y eliminarlo del mapa antes de meter un layer nuevo

Comment: Muy buenos días muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo resolví usando el removelayer, gracias por tu colaboración.